# Differentiability of $a:K\to \mathcal{B}(E,F)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Assume that $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an open subset and $E,F$ are Banach spaces.
Denote $\mathcal{B}(E,F)$ to be collection of all bounded linear operators from $E$ into $F.$
Endow $\mathcal{B}(E,F)$ with the [strong operator topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_operator_topology).

> Question: Suppose that $a:K\to \mathcal{B}(E,F)$ is a bounded linear operator.
>   To show that $a$ is differentiable at some $t_0\in K,$ what should we show?

I think we can show the following:

Fix $t_0\in K.$
For $e\in E,$ if $a(\cdot)e:K\to F$ is differentiable at $t_0,$ then we can conclude that $a$ is differentiable at $t_0.$

Am I right?

Comment: Any bounded linear operator is differentiable.

Comment: Yes, I know the fact. But how does it relate to my question?

Comment: You should use the correct definition of differentiablity. Your guess is anyway correct with the strong operator topology.

Comment: @downvoter May I know why downvote?

Comment: @Siminore What is the correct definition of differentiability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right.
$$\begin{eqnarray} &a(t)\text{ is differentiable at }t=t_0&  \\\iff& \text{strong limit } \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{a(t_0+h)-a(t_0)}{h}&\text{ exists in }\mathcal{B}(E,F). \\\iff&
\forall e \in E, \;\lim_{h\to 0} \left(\frac{a(t_0+h)-a(t_0)}{h}\right)(e)&\text{ exists in }F.\\
\iff&\forall e\in E,\; \lim_{h\to 0} \left(\frac{a(t_0+h)e-a(t_0)e}{h}\right)&\text{ exists in }F.\\
\iff&\forall e\in E,\; t\mapsto a(t)e\text{ is differentiable at }&t=t_0.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: I'm sorry for bringing up old question. In the limit, do we need to add norm to numerator?

Comment: You don't have to feel sorry, really. There are 3 limits that I used. The first one,which we denote by $L_1=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a(t_0+h)-a(t_0)}{h}$, does not involve the norm in $\mathcal{B}(E,F)$ because the convergence is about the strong topology (and not norm topology.) But the second and third involve the norm $\|\cdot\|_F$ on $F$; for instance, if we denote $L_3=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a(t_0+h)e-a(t_0)e}{h}$, it is just an equivalent expression to $$\left\|\frac{a(t_0+h)e-a(t_0)e}{h}-L_3\right\|_F\xrightarrow{h\to 0}0$$ or $$\frac{\|a(t_0+h)e-a(t_0)e-hL_3\|_F}{|h|}\xrightarrow{h\to 0}0.$$

Comment: I see. It is clearer to me now. Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it was helpful :)